# How to prevent informational messages from getting written when query results are output to a file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, command-line

When I am running the below query as a batch file (.BAT) using the Windows Task Scheduler, I am getting some informative messages in the output file *DatabaseNames.txt* in addition to the database names. How can I prevent those messages? These messages are not visible when running from the Command prompt.

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\psql.exe" --host localhost --username postgres -Atc "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datallowconn IS TRUE AND datname NOT IN('template0','template1')" > D:\Backup\DatabaseNames.txt
```

Below were the informative messages

> ```
> Welcome to PostgreSQL! 
> Type :version to see PostgreSQL version 
> Type :extensions to see the available extensions
> Time: 0.994 ms
> ```

Comment: I think you are looking for `psql -q ...` but it's hard to tell as `psql` does not great you with `Welcome to PostgreSQL!` and `Type :version to see PostgreSQL version` is also not part of a standard `psql` installation. Do you have a `%APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf` file for the Windows user running the batch file in the scheduler?

Comment: No I don't have a %APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf file. When I run the same .bat file from command prompt it works perfect without any messages. Kind of puzzled....

Comment: Oops my bad. I never created any .psqlrc file in my account, but I can see a .psqlrc file in the postgres account with these informative messages(not created by me). Does .psqlrc gets auto-created ?

Comment: The scheduler is using the postgres account for sure. Now I get it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently "someone" create a `psqlrc.conf` file that contains those messages you are seeing.

You can prevent `psql` from loading `psqlrc.conf` by passing the parameter `--no-psqlrc` (or `-X`). To hide the any other messages use the `--quiet` (or `-q`) parameter.

So your batch file should contain:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\psql.exe" --no-psqlrc --quiet --host localhost ...
```

Comment: If this answer has worked for you, please mark it as correct - that way others with the same problem will be able to find a solution more easily! Thanks :-)

Comment: Marking Done :)